# zend framework zf command not working

Tags: zend-framework, wamp

m using wamp and zend framework. firstly i had installed wamp localhost working fine then.
downloaded Zend framework.
added php path, zend library path in environment variable of windows.
enabled rewrite module and set include path in php.ini
which i get correct in phpinfo file.
after this m trying to execute

```
zf create project FirstProject
```

after this command on console i get an error

```
In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.

The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include
path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use,
then run the command "zf --setup".  This command is designed to create
a storage location for your user, as well as create the zf.ini file
that the zf command will consult in order to run properly on your
system.

To change the setup of this tool, run: "zf --setup"
```

thanks for ur help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you've added the php and library path but if you could make sure again that the your environment variables are definitley set correctly that would be great.

**NOTE: it's the bin directory that is needed for zend tool to work correctly.**

If still not working after this let me know and we can go from there.

Variable name: should be set to

```
Path
```

And the Variable value: should contain a link like

```
C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\bin;
```

Your link is likely to be different as I installed Zend Server in a different location from default and the framework is available through the 'share' directory.

Make sure the link you put in there points to the directory that the zf.bat (on a Windows system - I believe you're using WAMP) lives in and you should be able to test it's working from a command prompt using just the zf command.

To get to the GUI where you can update the environment variables:

```
1) Right click on the Computer icon on your Desktop and choose Properties option.
2) In the System window click on Advanced system settings in the left pane
3) In the System Properties window select Advanced tab and click on Environment Variables
4) In the Environment Variables window you will notice two columns - User variables for a username and System variables
5) In the System variables section scroll down to 'Path' and then highlight it and click 'Edit'
6) At the end of the last entry place a ; character and then paste the path to the ZendFramework\bin on your system like above
```

Hope this helps,

Dave

Comment: just one question i don't have Zend Server. i have only Zend Framework and zf.bat file path is added in the environment variable still it gives the error. i had installed Zend Server earlier but removed it afterwords is it necessary to install Zend Server? coz m following instructions from the beginners guide to Zend Framework n they have asked for zend framework only

Comment: in the command line type: php --ini and make sure you've been editing the correct php.ini for the CLI, sometimes there are two. Also make sure to restart apache and php after making changes. In windows it's usually easiest to log out and then log in.

Comment: yup m editing the correct php.ini when i run the test.php file containing phpinfo() function the include path contain zend library path but still getting the same error zf command not defined

Comment: Hi Rohan, just to say you don't need Zend Server to use the to use Zend_Tool (the ZF command line tool). If you paste the exact path you've set up in your environment variable in a comment for me that will help me help you. Make sure you open up your Environment Variables window then copy and paste it directly rather than manually typing it in.  Thanks, Dave  :-D

Comment: hi this is my environment variable path %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL51\bin;C:\ZendFramework\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8

Comment: Ok Rohan, it could be to do with permissions, now I noticed you've got a Zend folder under Program Files (x86).  In case it's a permissions issue try copying the ZendFramework folder into the Zend folder and place that path in the environment variables area.  Give it a go and let me know how you get on. Cheers, Dave

Comment: thnx i got rid of that error. now m facing new error n the error is  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Console\Console' not found i
n C:\Program Files (x86)\ZendFramework\bin\zf.php on line 611

Comment: No worries Rohan, are you using ZF v2 or are you using v1.11 or lower?  If ZF v2 you might find this link helpful.... http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-82  Let me know.  Cheers, Dave

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your getting this message means its finding the zf tool in bin just fine. Its the location of your zend library files its not finding. You must copy just the /Zend folder from the /library/Zend in the unzipped dir into some location. The preferred way is to copy the /Zend folder right into your php/includes folder and that way don't even have to add anything to your php.ini include_path parameter or you must at least un-comment it. So after you move the dir will look like /php/includes/Zend and the include_path will be 'c:\php\includes'

Answer (score 1):

"So after you move the dir will look like /php/includes/Zend and the include_path will be 'c:\php\includes'"

Im not a PHP pro developer, but I'd remark in the above good explanation that Andy gave, that you should be careful to set the include_path only with 'c:\php\includes' and not with 'c:\php\includes\Zend' as I supposed, and didn't work till I tested taking out the 'Zend' from the path ... hope this is useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple technique:

**STEP 1 :**  create a folder in your Program Files directory and name it  `ZendFrameworkCli`.

```
C:\Program Files\ZendFrameworkCli
```

**STEP 2 :**  copy `bin` and `library`  from your Zend Framework files and paste into above mentioned directory.

**SEPT 3 :**   set  paths going into system settings environment variables.
             For PHP it will be `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5;`
             and to use Zend from client `C:\Program Files\ZendFrameworkCli\bin;`