# zf command in Zend Framework outputs zf error on Windows

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, xampp

I have the same problem that this post [zend framework zf command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045270/zend-framework-zf-command-not-working) , but this post that I read several times doesn't solve my problem, I try what this post said but still does't work. I am with xampp and Windows 8. When I run "zf create Project quickstart" in command line I get this error:

> ***************************** ZF ERROR ********************************
>   In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
>   is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
>   ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
>   library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.
>
> The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include
>   path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or
>   ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use,
>   then run the command "zf --setup".  This command is designed to create
>   a storage location for your user, as well as create the zf.ini file
>   that the zf command will consult in order to run properly on your
>   system.
>
> Example you would run:
>
> $ ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/library zf --setup
>
> Your are encourged to read more in the link that follows.
>   Zend_Tool & CLI Setup Information
>   (available via the command line "zf --info")
>      * Home directory found in environment variable HOMEPATH with value \Users\myuser
>      * Storage directory assumed in home directory at location \Users\myuser/.zf/
>      * Storage directory does not exist at \Users\myuser/.zf/
>      * Config file assumed in home directory at location \Users\myuser/.zf.ini
>      * Config file does not exist at \Users\myuser/.zf.ini
>
> To change the setup of this tool, run: "zf --setup"

I do that:

Environment Variables->System variables->path and I add C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\bin
as the post I mention said, but that doesn't work.
I try to add a new variable in System variables call ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH with value C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library , I restart and also doesn't work. When I run "zf --setup"  I have the same error. I copy zf.bat and zf.php in C:\xampp\php.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this path `C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library` in your `php's include path` by adding this line in your **php.ini** file.

If you are using `xampp` in `windows` you will find **php.ini** here `C:\xampp\php`

You should find this in your **php.ini**:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

Your should add you **Zend Framework library path** like this in your **php.ini**:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library"
```

Now you can run your **zftool** from your **command-line** from here:

```
C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\bin>zf create Project quickstart
```

For more: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html